# Mapping Drives for VPN using CMAK

Tags: vpn, batch-file

I'm creating a connection file for VPN using microsoft CMAK. The VPN connection works but when I try to map drives it maps the drive under the Administrator account on the local machine because the VPN setup EXE needs elevated administrator account to install.

I'm adding this batch file to the CMAK setup under 'Add Custom Action -> Post Connect'.

```
net use J: \\Server\Share1$ /persistent:no
net use K: \\Server\Share2$ /persistent:no
```

I've also tried 'Runas' for local %USERNAME% but that required me to enter local passwords and administrator server passwords to map the drives, this will be too much for our users to do and I would like this installation to be as silent as possible.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

S